# Problem in demonstration of Bloch theorem

Tags: solid-state-physics

i'm into one of the demonstration of the Bloch's theorem, in the beginning. I've introduced a translation operator $ T_{\vec{a}}$ that brings a function $f(\vec{r})$ into $f(\vec{r}+\vec{a})$, that in Dirac representation reads as $\langle{\vec{r}}|T_{\vec{a}}|f\rangle=\langle{\vec{r}}+\vec{a}|f\rangle$. Now, in the thermodynamic limit, where the region of space $\Omega \longrightarrow \infty $, it can be shown that 
$$ \langle f|T^{\dagger}_{\vec{a}}T_{\vec{a}}|f\rangle=\int_{\Omega \rightarrow\infty} d\vec{r} f^{*}(\vec{r}+\vec{a})f(\vec{r}+\vec{a}) = \langle{f}|f\rangle $$ for every $|f\rangle$. Now, I understand the result, because integration over an infinite interval is not affected by a finite translation, but I have some difficulty in deriving the above formula. My idea is that I can use the completeness relation for a continuous index $|\vec{r}\rangle$,
$$ \hat{1} = \int |\vec{r}\rangle d\vec{r}\langle\vec{r}|$$ 
to write 
$$ \langle f|T^{\dagger}_{\vec{a}}T_{\vec{a}}|f\rangle = \int_{\Omega \rightarrow\infty} \langle f|T^{\dagger}_{\vec{a}}|\vec{r}\rangle d\vec{r}\langle\vec{r}|T_{\vec{a}}|f\rangle  $$
$$= \int_{\Omega \rightarrow\infty} \langle f|\vec{r}+\vec{a}\rangle d\vec{r}\langle\vec{r}+\vec{a}|f\rangle $$
That leads to
$$\int_{\Omega \rightarrow\infty} d\vec{r} f^{*}(\vec{r}+\vec{a})f(\vec{r}+\vec{a})$$ But I'm not sure my derivation is mathematically correct. Can someone help? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: That looks fine to me. What exactly aren't you comfortable with?

Comment: My idea is to insert the 1 between the two operators, but I'm not sure I'm legitimate to take the operators and the <f| inside the integral, I just have the suspect I can..

Comment: Sure, you can do this because integration (and the operators) are linear, it's fine.